# Increase PHP-FPM's max upload/post size

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, php.ini

I'm running php5-fpm under Nginx on Ubuntu 14.04. I want to increase the max upload size.

I have edited my `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini` to have the following lines defined as below:

`upload_max_filesize = 20M
post_max_size = 25M`

and I restarted php5-fpm and nginx but `phpinfo()` is still showing the limits to be 8M and 2M for post and upload respectively.

Is there anything I have missed here?

Comment: check if the php.ini path in phpinfo() is same as you mentioned the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue was with the restarting of php5-fpm. It seems there is a bug where sometimes some child processes are not terminated upon restart. I had to manually kill the processes with `kill <process id>` having identified them with `ps -ef`.

I was then able to fully restart php5-fpm which enacted my config changes.

Answer (score 65):

Nginx

- `client_max_body_size`

PHP

- `post_max_size`
- `upload_max_filesize`

And restart or reload php fpm.

Source: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size

Comment: Which file to put this in for PHP? conf.d/mysite.ini or pool.d/mysite.ini?

Comment: @Jonathan in my case, on Ubuntu 20.04, I put the PHP settings in `/etc/php/7.4/fpm/php.ini` and the Nginx setting in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com` to only affect that single site

Answer (score 28):

Instead  of  changing php.ini file, I add all information in the nginx sites-available files. I see you got your answer long time ago, but this is the way I do it:

In my virtualhost under server {} block, I added:

`client_max_body_size 128m;`

Then in the location ~ .php$ {} block I added:

`fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "upload_max_filesize=128M \n post_max_size=128M";`

Then restart nginx.

Answer (score 13):

I had a problem with restarting so I just killed the process and started it manually.

```
sudo pkill php5-fpm
sudo service php5-fpm start
```

Comment: This seems a comment on the answer accepted in 2014

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question that's already been answered. But I wanted to comment here for @harryg and others that come after me.

Your issue was with restarting php5-fpm being buggy. As of this writing, the issue seems to have been fixed, and restarting php5-fpm on ubuntu is as simple as running the following command:

```
service php5-fpm restart
```

NOTE: I'm currently running this version of php5-fpm: `PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.9 (fpm-fcgi) (built: Apr 17 2015 11:44:58)`

Hope someone finds this helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It sets the maximum allowed size of the client request body, specified in the “Content-Length” request header field. Here’s an example of increasing the limit to 50MB in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file.

Set in http block which affects all server blocks (virtual hosts).

```
http {
    ...
    client_max_body_size 50M;
}
```

Set in server block, which affects a particular site/app

```
server {
    ...
    client_max_body_size 50M;
}
```

Set in location block, which affects a particular directory (uploads) under a site/app.

```
location /uploads {
    ...
    client_max_body_size 50M;
}
```

Save the file and restart Nginx web server to apply the recent changes using following command.

```
# systemctl restart nginx
```

Comment: this configures apache, not php

Comment: No, this for php5-fpm under Nginx configuration.

Comment: these are options for nginx's ngx_http_core_module. Definitely do not configure any php settings.